# How to set value/term of a Woocommerce attribute text field in admin panel?

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic, customization

I am developing a plugin which is supposed to auto-fill the attributes text field.

There is a URL text field where user enters URL, on focus out I trigger a AJAX call through which I am able to save the data but I am looking to accomplish here is to show the saved data on highlighted fields as well.

[image]

I am using following code in a hook to display:

```
if( function_exists( 'wc_get_attribute_taxonomies' ) && ( $attribute_taxonomies = wc_get_attribute_taxonomies() ) ) {

    $defaults = array();
    $name = wc_attribute_taxonomy_name( $tax->attribute_name );
    foreach ( $attribute_taxonomies as $key=>$tax ) {
                $defaults[ $name ] = array (
                    'name' => $name,
                    'value' => 'thisTextShouldAppearInHighlightedFieldsOfScreenShot',
                    'position' => $key+1,
                    'is_visible' => 1,
                    'is_variation' => 1,
                    'is_taxonomy' => 1,
                );

            update_post_meta( $post->ID , '_product_attributes', $defaults );
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming the ID of that text filed, is **url-field** here is the JS code

```
$("#url-field").keyup(function(event) {
     var url_val=$("#url-field").val();
      $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url: ajaxurl,
            data: {
                action:'use_someprefix_update_url',
                search_string:url_val,
                namefiled : namehere,
                postid : postidhereYouCangetItIHope  
            },
            success:function(data){
               alert("Success, you can remove me :-) ");
            }
        });
});
```

Here comes PHP, put this in functions.php

```
function use_someprefix_update_url(){
    $defaults = array();
    $defaults[ $_POST['namefiled'] ] = array (
                    'name' => $_POST['namefiled'],
                    'value' => $_POST['search_string'],
                );
     update_post_meta( $_POST['postid'] , '_product_attributes', $defaults );
}
```

Also this Hook also :

```
add_action('wp_ajax_use_someprefix_update_url', 'use_someprefix_update_url');
```

P.S : You have to do validation stuff.